# Number of users in a Stack Overflow SEDE query

Tags: support, data-explorer, users

I tried to run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/edit/1573096) on SEDE:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.Displayname DESC) AS row,
        u.Id, u.Reputation
      FROM
        Users u
      WHERE
        u.reputation > ##MinimumRep:int?100##
    ) dt
WHERE
    row >= ##StartRow:INT?1##
    AND row <= ##EndRow:INT?50000##
ORDER BY
    row
```

However, paginating after the 1,200,000th row, I can't receive any results, even though SO has 17 million users.

Is there any limit?

Comment: if you did run with the minumum rep on 100 you miss out on a large group of users

Comment: @rene any proposal how I could run this query properly to receive all users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. Your link is `https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/edit/1573096` so your running your query against the *Meta* Stack Overflow database. Stack Overflow users only have a [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) account if they ever visit it, so you miss out on a lot of users (see below).
2. There are only 1.15 million Stack Overflow users with a reputation of at least 100 (which your query seems to filter on), not 17 million.

See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1573133) for some statistics:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to include all users and not only users that have > 100 reputation.

If I run [your query with said restriction set to 0](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1573124?MinimumRep=0) I get 17m rows.

[image]